# Using characters to separate menus in navigation bar

Tags: navigation

I’m attempting to modify my blog's navigation menu (http://reasonandfolly.com/) to replicate what is here: http://chimpchomp.us/

Two pieces represent a challenge: 1. The separators 2. The line on right/left of menus.

I’m fairly new to WP and can’t be certain if this requires a change to CSS or PHP.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to give you an exact answer because I don't know the PHP code you are using to print the menu. You will need to have a loop and insert a // between the `<LI>` elements, except for the very last one because you don't want a // at the end of the menu.

For the CSS/HTML part you can follow chimpchomp's lead and insert a span between each `<li>`, like this:

```
<li>HOME</li>
<span>//</span>
<li>HOME</li>
```

You will need to amend the margin betern each LI so that the // appears exactly centred between the menu options. You have this at the moment:

```
header nav ul li {
display: inline;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
padding: 0;
}
```

You could change this so that the margin is the same for left and right, something like:

```
margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
```

Comment: I'll try to digest in small pieces and see if I can catch up.. by menu php code, I imagine this is what you're looking for? (from header.php)                        </div><!-- /logo -->
    <nav>
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' =>  __('Main Menu', 'meanthemes'), 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_id' => false, 'menu_class' => false ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- /nav -->
   </div> 
  </header><!-- /header -->

Comment: I can see the <li>HOME</li> in html via firebug but can't tell which file needs to be edited to affect that change.